# laravel 5.7 + vue.js 2 + laravel echo + pusher, how to make them work together?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

I am able to configure Laravel Echo with Pusher and install all the necessary dependencies. I have watch tutorials on lynda and laracast how to do this, but they are old and not for these versions in the title of this question. So, from what i have learned so far from lynda and laracast i have to run Vue from the blade template, but i cant make this work unless i add manual this line of code `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>` inside my blade engine. i am sure this is not the way things have to work as i am getting two instances of vue by added this line of code inside my blade template. I cant make it work as i am getting `Vue is not defined` if i use it inside my blade template this way:

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
        data() {
           return {
                ...
           }
        },
)}
```

So, even when i run two instances of Vue i can't get the laravel Echo to work from Blade as when i use it i am getting `Echo is not defined` for example using this code:

```
Echo.join('form.' + '{{ $product->id }}')
    .here((users) => {
         this.count = users.length;
    });
```

I also tried using `window` like this:

```
window.Echo.join('form.' + '{{ $product->id }}')
    .here((users) => {
         this.count = users.length;
    });
```

But that way i am getting `Cannot read property 'join' of undefined"`

So basically i am lost trying to figure it out how to use vue inside the blade the proper way + laravel echo and pusher js.

**UPDATED**

here is my app.js file:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('search-component', require('./components/Search.vue'));
```

and here is my boostrap.js file:

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true
});
```

Comment: We will need more information to help you with this. What is your frontend build setup? Are you using laravel mix? Post your mix configuration and your main js file that contains the Vue instantiation. If you are using mix you have to install the dependencies like echo and vue via npm install and then import / require them in your main.js or whatever you called it. By this you will be able to use it. I don't see any reason to include the script for Vue into your blade. The default setup with mix will not require this.

Comment: @FrankProvost, well i see on all courses that people are using laravel echo together with vue inside the blade template isnt it that the right way of using it and if i want to write some small js logic using vue isnt it the right way to just write it inside the blade template instead of creating a separate component just for that + i have some logic inside the blade template i want to use and i cant do it with the vue component, i am doing things the wrong way?

Comment: @FrankProvost, and yes, i am using laravel mix, mainly i compile my js and css files using the official documentation with `npm run watch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after day of searching i finally manage to make vue/echo/pusher/dash to work from blade template. for more info and reference to actual working code, please check this [github repo](https://github.com/jacurtis/Packt-Laravel-Echo/blob/master/resources/views/posts/show.blade.php)

I will try to write a guite how to do this step by step:

1. Make sure you are running the latest version of **npm**. this is essential. (mine is 6.4.1)
2. After installing laravel run `npm install`
3. Inside `bootstrap.js` file this code

   ```
   import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
   window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
   window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
     encrypted: true
   });
   ```
4. Register to pusher.com and create an app. Fill out your data from pusher to .env file (like app id, secret, cluster and etc)
5. (Optional) Comment out this code from app.js as you dont need it (if you are using it dont do it, but in most cases you never will)

   ```
   // const app = new Vue({
   //   el: '#app',
   // });
   ```
6. Go to the main blade template of your app in my case it is called app.blade.php and under the `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` add this line of code `@yield('scripts')`. now you can add scripts to your blade templates
7. Now you can create your script section inside your blade template using `@section('scripts')` for benning tag and `@endsection` for closing tag
8. here is a simple js code how to use Vue and Echo after you opened the script section:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     let app = new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       data() {
         return {
           viewers: [],
           count: 0,
         }
       },
       mounted() {
         this.listen();
       },
       methods: {
         listen() {
           Echo.join('chat.' + '{{ $take->id }}')
             .here((users) => {
               this.count = users.length;
               this.viewers = users;
              })
              .joining((user) => {
                this.count++;
                this.viewers.push(user);
               })
               .leaving((user) => {
                 this.count--;
                 _.pullAllBy(this.viewers, [user]);
               });
           }
       },
   });
   ```